# How to pass "bitmap" as argument using safe args

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-safe-args

I want to pass `Bitmap`as an argument to another fragment using safe args. what is the correct `argType` for passing a bitmap.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nextFragment"
        android:name="com.example.----.NextFragment"
        android:label="fragment_next"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_next" >
        <argument
            android:name="image"
            app:argType="???"
            android:defaultValue="???" />
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add argType  as `android.graphics.Bitmap`

from the source code of NavType.java

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
                if (Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                    return new ParcelableType(clazz);
                } else if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                    return new EnumType(clazz);
                } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                    return new SerializableType(clazz);
                }
```

And Bitmap implements parcelable, so it will work.

You can remove the defaultValue

Comment: thankz, but there is a problem, i want the bitmap to be null-able, and it is not allowing me to do it , Error: `Null can not be a value of a non-null type Bitmap`, how to fix it?.. am using kotlin

Comment: @Askani Adding `app:nullable="true"` to argument definition should help.